# Convert a vector into a specialised list efficiently

Tags: r

I'm looking for a *more* efficient way to get from my current input to my expected output.

Input

```
vec <- 1:4
```

Expected output

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 3

[[5]]
[1] 4
```

Current solution:

```
lis <- list()
lis[2:5] <- as.list(vec)
lis[[1]] <- vec
```

Comment: What's you question?

Comment: How to get in the most efficient way from my current input to my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
c(list(vec), as.list(vec))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 1

#[[3]]
#[1] 2

#[[4]]
#[1] 3

#[[5]]
#[1] 4
```

Comment: . Makes perfect sense.